# Resource Routing on mutiple URLs

Tags: stash, routing, resource-router

Just jumping into [Resource Router](https://github.com/rsanchez/resource_router) by [Rob Sanchez](https://twitter.com/_rsan) and hit a wall already. I've forgone the category URL indicator as I believe it works without it. I'm attempting to achieve the following URL structure:

/posts/ *-Display a list of ALL categories*

/posts/category_url *-Display a list of entries belonging to the category*

/posts/category_url/entry_url *-Display an entry that has the category*

I currently have:

```
$env_config['resource_router'] = array(
        'posts/:category/:any' => function($router, $wildcard_1, $wildcard_2) {
                // is segment_3 a valid URL title?
                if ($wildcard_2->isValidUrlTitle()) {
                    $router->setTemplate('templates/view');
                }   //is segment_2 a valid category URL title?
                elseif ($wildcard_1->isValidCategoryUrlTitle()) {
                    $router->setTemplate('templates/cat_entries');
                } 
                else { //We're at the root - show category list
                    $router->setTemplate('templates/cat_overview');
                }
         }
);
```

The Valid URL title portion works but stumped on what I require to get the other 2 working. Any insight gratefully accepted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this without a callback function:

```
$config['resource_router'] = array(
    'posts' => 'templates/index',
    'posts/:category_url_title' => 'templates/cat_entries',
    'posts/:category_url_title/:any' => 'templates/view',
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I've done it before:

```
posts/:any           => templates/index,
posts/:any/:any      => templates/cat_entries,
posts/:any/:any/:any => templates/view
```

Comment: Marked Rob's as the answer as it had that little more error checking then a simple `:any approach`. Much appreciated the speed of your help however.